# object, key value combinations in two objects

Tags: python, list

I have a list of KV's that looks like:

```
{'0-4': 0, '86-90': 0, '30-34': 0, '35-39': 0, '25-29': 0, '10-14': 0, '76-80': 0, '40-44': 0, '5-9': 0, '50': 0, '61-65': 0, '91-95': 0, '51-55': 0, '96-100': 0, '81-85': 0, '56-60': 0, '15-19': 0, '66-70': 0, '20-24': 0, '45-49': 0, '71-75': 0}
```

I then have an object of tuples I believe that hold KV's..

```
[(0, 4L), (5, 2L), (10, 2L), (15, 4L), (20, 5L), (25, 4L), (30, 4L), (35, 2L), (40, 1L), (45, 1L), (51, 7L), (56, 2L), (61, 4L), (66, 4L), (71, 4L), (76, 4L), (81, 8L), (86, 2L), (91, 1L), (96, 2L)]
```

My goal is to take the number of the key in the 2nd object, and match it to the first number of the number-range in the first object. And set the value of that key to the value of the matching pair from the second object. (i.e. - '0-4' would get the value(4) from the second object where key is '0'. the number-range '5-6' would get the value(2) from '5' and so on).

Below is the final return im looking to create using both objects(value from object 2 inserted into object 1 at matching number-range):

```
{'0-4': 4, '86-90': 2, '30-34': 4, '35-39': 2, '25-29': 4, '10-14': 2, '76-80': 4, '40-44': 1, '5-9': 2, '50': 0, '61-65': 4, '91-95': 1, '51-55': 7, '96-100': 2, '81-85': 8, '56-60': 2, '15-19': 4, '66-70': 4, '20-24': 5, '45-49': 1, '71-75': 4}
```

The point of this is to set a default objects values all to 0 because the second object may be missing some of the matching number-ranges. You'll notice there is no '50' in the second object. In my app any of these ranges could be missing at any time from the second object. So I am setting all the number-ranges to 0 and then revaluing each range if its in the second object.

#### Things I've tried:

I have tried looping over either list and doing a search for 'key' IN object 2 key name. This seems to always return NO as I think the object types don't match.

In found a similar question on stack overflow that had me do something like this:

```
new_dict = dict((k, v) for k, v in dict.iteritems() if k in list)
```

This also didn't work.

Comment: Show your latest code attempt and specify in reference to the code what are you believe the problem lies. The community can then point you in the right direction based on the work you have already started.

Comment: why not use real tuples for they keys in the first dictionary? `{(0, 4): 0, (86, 90): 0, (30, 34): 0, (35, 39): 0, (25, 29): 0, (10, 14): 0, (76, 80): 0, (40, 44): 0, (5, 9): 0}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the first number of the number-range we'll use *split('-')* and get its first value. Then we convert it to an integer. To look up numbers from the second object we'll convert it to a dictionary.
Here's the resulting code:

```
a = {'0-4': 0, '86-90': 0, '30-34': 0, '35-39': 0, '25-29': 0, '10-14': 0, '76-80': 0, '40-44': 0, '5-9': 0, '50': 0, '61-65': 0, '91-95': 0, '51-55': 0, '96-100': 0, '81-85': 0, '56-60': 0, '15-19': 0, '66-70': 0, '20-24': 0, '45-49': 0, '71-75': 0}
b = [(0, 4L), (5, 2L), (10, 2L), (15, 4L), (20, 5L), (25, 4L), (30, 4L), (35, 2L), (40, 1L), (45, 1L), (51, 7L), (56, 2L), (61, 4L), (66, 4L), (71, 4L), (76, 4L), (81, 8L), (86, 2L), (91, 1L), (96, 2L)]

b2 = dict(b)
c = {k: b2.get(int(k.split('-')[0]), 0) for k, v in a.items()}
```

Comment: Calling `dict(b)` every time is egregiously inefficient, though perhaps it doesn’t matter if the input is (and stays) this small.

Answer (score 0):

It’s easiest (and, with lots of values, fastest) to make the second list into a dictionary: you can just call `dict` on it.  Then use a dictionary comprehension that splits the string keys, converts the first to a number, and indexes the converted dictionary with it.  Use `dict2.get(val,0)` to apply the default.

Comment: I guess the question would come down to then, If i convert object 2 into a dict, and I loop through object 1, how do I get the if statement to say `IF (first number of number-range) IN the newly made dict()` then obviously set the value of the index item I am on in the first loop.

Comment: @Ugsquish: You _can_ use `val in dict2`, but with the `get` I just added you need no test and can use the comprehension (which also avoids having to “set” anything).

Answer (score 0):

Assume you call the KV `dict` and the list of tuples `lst`. For every typle go through the dictionary and find an appropriate key, then add the value to it. You'll need `split('-')` to obtain the numbers that specify the range and then test it.

```
for k, v in lst:
    for key in dict:
        r = key.split('-')
        if int(r[0]) < k < int(r[1]):
            dict[key] += v
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one too:

```
for i in inList:
    for j in inDict:
        if int(j.split('-')[0])==i[0]:
            inDict[j]=i[1]

print(inDict)
```

Output:

```
{'45-49': 1, '0-4': 4, '96-100': 2, '81-85': 8, '51-55': 7, '25-29': 4, '56-60': 2, '20-24': 5, '35-39': 2, '10-14': 2, '50': 0, '76-80': 4, '66-70': 4, '30-34': 4, '40-44': 1, '86-90': 2, '15-19': 4, '91-95': 1, '5-9': 2, '61-65': 4, '71-75': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary comprehension and for each key, create a dictionary of `d` and access the value stored for the first part of the original string key in s:

```
s = {'0-4': 0, '86-90': 0, '30-34': 0, '35-39': 0, '25-29': 0, '10-14': 0, '76-80': 0, '40-44': 0, '5-9': 0, '50': 0, '61-65': 0, '91-95': 0, '51-55': 0, '96-100': 0, '81-85': 0, '56-60': 0, '15-19': 0, '66-70': 0, '20-24': 0, '45-49': 0, '71-75': 0}
d = [(0, 4L), (5, 2L), (10, 2L), (15, 4L), (20, 5L), (25, 4L), (30, 4L), (35, 2L), (40, 1L), (45, 1L), (51, 7L), (56, 2L), (61, 4L), (66, 4L), (71, 4L), (76, 4L), (81, 8L), (86, 2L), (91, 1L), (96, 2L)]
new_s = {a:int(dict(d).get(int(a.split('-')[0]), 0)) for a, b in s.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'0-4': 4, '86-90': 2, '30-34': 4, '35-39': 2, '10-14': 2, '25-29': 4, '56-60': 2, '40-44': 1, '5-9': 2, '50': 0, '61-65': 4, '91-95': 1, '51-55': 7, '96-100': 2, '81-85': 8, '76-80': 4, '15-19': 4, '66-70': 4, '71-75': 4, '45-49': 1, '20-24': 5}
```

Comment: Why call `dict(d)` anew every time?